# How to group messages in a chat instead of having each new message in a new section?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm building a chat system with React and socket.io, and I'm trying to achieve grouping messages together like Discord does it, or as seen in [this screenshot](https://www.livechatinc.com/app/livechat-mobile-app.5e4cb448468d20b89b5b1609890dd47d0da74ef466d4ca84c2673958328607b4.png). Basically, instead of creating a new section with your avatar again, it will just create a new message element and append it to your pre-existing section, **unless** the other user you're chatting with sends you a message **or** if it has been too long since your last message (in this case, 1 minute).

[Link to JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/AkkeHS/27gr93xa/)

The brown messages are my messages, and the black are the other users'.

What I first thought was the correct solution was to group every message by 1 minute.

```
const sortByMinute = _.groupBy(messages, (msg) => {
    return moment(msg.createdAt * 1000).startOf("minute").format();
});
```

However, the problem with doing this, as seen in the fiddle, is that it completely ignores when another users sends a message. So when another user sends you a message, it still thinks it belongs in the same section, because it has no way to determine whether it comes from a new user or not, and frankly, I have no clue how to do it either.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should do a look-behind, and start a new section if the previous message doesn't belong to the same user as the user that sent the "current" message.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by look-behind? First time I hear that expression.

Comment: There's no library function that I know of, but you should just use a standard for loop to iterate through your collection and determine when to start the new section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did: I divided the whole process in two steps:

1. Group the message by user (you'll need to add you 1 minute condition)

```js
let lastMsg = lastMessages[lastMessages.length - 1]
            if (lastMsg.user === m.user) {
        lastMessages.push(m)
        acc[acc.length - 1] = lastMessages
      } else {
        acc.push([m])
      }
      return acc;
    }, [[firstMsg]])
```

2. Create the data structure that you use to display the messages.

```js
const groups = newMessages.reduce((acc, m) => {
        const message = m[m.length - 1]
      acc[moment(message.createdAt * 1000).format()] = m
      return acc
    }, {})
```

Check the example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lw8gs6x7/

Note: you'll need to refactor my code. It is not very clean.

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking your time looking into my issue, it's not often someone does that around here. Secondly, this partly achieves the job (like you said, it doesn't support the 1-minute rule), but it is definitely something I can work with and improve further!